# Managing bootstrap.php in Kohana 3

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

We are currently using Kohana 3 for a staging application which is getting ready for production. We have few requirements to set custom routing and custom error codes. Most of the solutions offered in Kohana 3 suggests modifying bootstrap.php directly. Is that a best practice to do? In Kohana 2.x, they had something like [routes.php](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/general/routing) as part of configuration. I believe that is replaced by regular expression routing in Kohana 3 which is placed inside bootstrap.php along with other out-of-box settings.

Please suggest the best practice followed by Kohana 3 community. I don't mind changing bootstrap.php but wondering if there is any configuration files specifically for routing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single best practice. But if you have many routes (and usually you have), I suggest you to create a new file `routes.php` in `application` folder and include it in `bootstrap.php`.

So instead of `Route::set('default'...` in your `bootstrap.php` you will have `require_once APPPATH.'routes.php';`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. waiting for other answers, if any, before accepting this.